# Row_Count() Not working within a stored procedure via PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, toad

If I use a client to connect to mySQL, such as toad and call my procedure

I have a stored procedure, with one part of the code being

```
UPDATE table Set ...
Where...;
Select Row_Count() Into insertCount;
Select Case insertCount When 0 Then 0 Else 1 End As success;
```

When I call this procedure from Toad for MySQL it works perfectly, when I call it from PDO the update works but success always returns 0.  This is even when I use exactly the same call, hard-coding the parameters.

Does anybody understand why this might happen?

PHP Code:

```
    function getDBResults($sql, $params=array()) {
        global $dbConn;

        if ($dbConn==null) { // If there's no connection, do it local
            $bLocalConn = true;
            dbConnect(true);    
        } else {
            $bLocalConn = false;
        }

        if (!is_array($params)) {
            $params = array($params);
        }


        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
        $dbConn->commit();

        if ($bLocalConn==true) { //Close connection if made locally
            dbConnect(false);   
        }
    }
```

Works the same even without bind variables.

Comment: please add your php code

Comment: and just to check PHP, it does think it is a success if I edit the select to "Select 1 success;"

Comment: so, is `Row_Count()` some custom function you're using? If not, then the syntax is `rowCount()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @Fred, no it isn't http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Comment: ah ok. thanks for that.

Comment: thanks for the indent fix Fred :)

Comment: you're welcome Denzil.

Comment: Can you show the code you have in `$sql`?

Comment: Also, you have `->commit()` after the `return` statement.